# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I got this error in console tab.

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined"

My code works normally but I don't know why that error shows up. I think it because the DOM has rendered first then my data was populated after that. Is that true? If yes, how can I fix it?

Here is my component:

```
<template>
    <main role="main">

        <!--        <breadcrumbs></breadcrumbs>-->

        <slider></slider>
        <bestseller :products="serverData.bestsellerProducts.products"></bestseller>
        <categorized-products></categorized-products>
        <latest :products="serverData.latestProducts.products"></latest>

    </main>
</template>

<script>
    import Slider from './Slider';
    import Bestseller from './Product/Bestseller';
    import Latest from './Product/Latest';
    import CategorizedProducts from './ProductCategory/CategorizedProducts';
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                serverData: 'getServerData'
            })
        },
        components: {
            Slider,
            Bestseller,
            Latest,
            CategorizedProducts
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Use [Conditional Rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), ie `v-if`

Comment: I did try it, but it still shows that error: `<bestseller v-if="serverData.bestsellerProducts" :products="serverData.bestsellerProducts.products"></bestseller>`

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when your component renders before `serverData` is available. You should init this variable first in your state. Something like:

```
state: {
    serverData: {
        bestsellerProducts: {products: []},
        latestProducts: {products: []},
    }
}
```

I'd recommend separating `bestSellerProducts` and `latestProducts` from `serverData`.

Also make sure you handle props properly inside components. See [Vue Document on Props Validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation).

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen Kien, but my serverData variable is dynamic. I am going to populate data depend controller, so I cannot init variable like your solution.

Comment: @JoshuaHansen you can always change the values in your state later. The code in this answer just sets up the initial data so you don't get errors

Comment: @JoshuaHansen: Then you should separate this `serverData` variable into different smaller ones. It will help when later on you need to debug, you only concern with certain set data, not all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either `bestsellerProducts` or `latestProducts` doesn't have a `products` attribute. If you could post the value for these two items I'd be able to give you a better answer.

Are you pushing to the array after the render?

Comment: I already checked in Vue Devtool, it has a product attribute, that why my code is working and rendering products.

Comment: try making it asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

This method is kind of ghetto but:

You could make an error handler then if the error contains that text return the function otherwise console.error() it.